# coc-clangd disable snippet completion not working

Tags: neovim, coc.nvim

I don't like the snippet completion that coc-clangd is providing me, so I wrote `"clangd.disableSnippetCompletion": true` in coc-settings.json, but it's not working. Snippets are still in my suggestion list, and even in primary positions.

Here is my coc-settings.json file.

```json
{
    "languageserver": {
      "coc-clangd": {
        "command": "clangd",
        "rootPatterns": ["compile_flags.txt", "compile_commands.json"],
        "filetypes": ["c", "cc", "cpp", "c++", "objc", "objcpp"],
        "clangd.arguments": ["--enable-cxx20"],
        "clangd.disableSnippetCompletion": true
      }
    },
    "rust-analyzer.enable": true,
    "rust-analyzer.inlayHints.enable": true,
    "rust-analyzer.cargo.buildScripts.enable": false,
    "pyright-enable": true,
    "suggest.enablePreselect": false,
    "suggest.noselect": true,
    "snippets.priority": 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues with your configurations:

1. you don't need to setup `clangd` in `languageserver` if you're using coc-clangd
2. put `clangd.disableSnippetCompletion` in root section in coc-settings.json